C++ Apache Arrow Schema --- ListArray ("item" with "repetition": "Required")
I am asking this question using the full example ("row to columnar conversion, Fixed Schemas") from Apache Arrow website https://arrow.apache.org/docs/dev/cpp/examples/row_columnar_conversion.html
In the website example, the schema vector is defined to be
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>> schema_vector = {
  arrow::field("id", arrow::int64()),
  arrow::field("components", arrow::int64()), 
  arrow::field("component_cost", arrow::list(arrow::float64()))
};

Hence, the schema detail of "component_cost" would show for the "list item" to be
"fields": {"PrimitiveType": { "field_info": { "name": "item", "repetition": "Optional", "id": null }, "logical_type": null, "converted_type": null, "physical_type": "Double" } }

Meaning that the element repetition is optional within the list array!
In my use case, if I want to make sure that the element repetition is required within the list array, and I tried the following to output the parquet in my local drive (i.e. I changed the "schema_vector" compared to the above one used in the Apache Arrow website)
struct data_row {
  int64_t id;
  int64_t components;
  std::vector<double> component_cost;
};

void VectorToColumnarTable(const std::vector<struct data_row>& rows) {
  // Create filepath
  std::filesystem::path file_path = "C:/my_example/example.parquet";
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile {};
  PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(outfile, arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(file_path.string()));

  arrow::MemoryPool* pool = arrow::default_memory_pool();
  arrow::Int64Builder id_builder(pool);
  arrow::Int64Builder components_builder(pool);
  arrow::ListBuilder component_cost_builder(pool, std::make_shared<arrow::DoubleBuilder>(pool));
  arrow::DoubleBuilder* component_item_cost_builder =
      (static_cast<arrow::DoubleBuilder*>(component_cost_builder.value_builder()));

  for (const data_row& row : rows) {
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(id_builder.Append(row.id));
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(components_builder.Append(row.components));

    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(component_cost_builder.Append());
    PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(
        component_item_cost_builder->AppendValues(row.component_cost.data(), row.component_cost.size()));
  }
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> id_array;
  PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK((id_builder.Finish(&id_array)));
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> components_array;
  PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK((components_builder.Finish(&components_array)));
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> component_cost_array;
  PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK((component_cost_builder.Finish(&component_cost_array)));

  // My schema vector -----> different to the website one
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>> schema_vector = {
      arrow::field("id", arrow::int64()),
      arrow::field("components", arrow::int64()),
      arrow::field("component_cost", arrow::list(arrow::field("item", arrow::float64(), false)))};

  std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> table = arrow::Table::Make(arrow::schema(schema_vector), {id_array, components_array, component_cost_array});
  PARQUET_THROW_NOT_OK(parquet::arrow::WriteTable(*table, arrow::default_memory_pool(), outfile, 100));

}


However, in the "WriteTable" bit, the code crashed out completely and I could not figure what I have done wrong here.
Any suggestion here, many thanks!!!
I tried the above way, and it could not work
I simply would to output the parquet file to my local drive, where the schema for the list item within "component_cost" to be
"fields": { "PrimitiveType": { "field_info": { "name": "item", "repetition": "Required", "id": null }, "logical_type": null, "converted_type": null, "physical_type": "Double" } }

Meaning that the element repetition is required within the list array!

What do you mean by "crashed out completely"? Can you put the error message in your question. Also can you show the code that creates the component_cost_array.

yes, just updated the code above
then in terms of "crash out completely"
i ran the above in VS studio --------> i crashed at the "WriteToTable" bit -------> then i used call stack, but it showed as
"throw.cpp not found: Source link authentication failed"
